# Reliable BLE Advertisements

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I need to periodically transmit and scan LE Advertisements between two phones while also modifying the transmit power level. I need to do this as reliably and with the lowest possible latency. The aim behind this is to obtain RSSI measurements corresponding to different TxPowerLevels as frequently as possible.

So far this is done by restarting the advertisements every time the TxPowerLevel needs to be modified (stopadvertisement followed by startadvertisement), however this introduces large latencies for the first advertising packet. Additionally, there is a bottleneck lying in the scan interval. It seems I can only achieve scanning every 300ms.

Could anyone provide some ideas on achieving lower latencies. Is it possible to modify the TxPowerLevels on running advertisements? Is it possible to regularly poll the RSSI on the received-side and modify the TxPowerLevels on the transmitter-side between paired devices (as opposed to LE advertisements)?

Thanks!

Comment: I would hazard to say you are pretty much stuck with what Android has to offer. Some hardware vendors won't even let you change TX power between advertisement packets, or will require you restart advertising to take effect. My I ask why you need this? Signal attenuation does not depend on the power of the transmitted signal, only on the signal path (distance, obstacles, reflectors, etc.). For example, a path with a 10-dB loss will cause a 0 [dBm] signal to be received at -10 [dBm], and a -10 [dBm] signal to be received at -20 [dBm]

Comment: Thanks for your help! So far I have been doing that only by restarting advertisements. I have noticed that it is possible to do so within running advertisements and in between packets by using the beacon library for example. However, the concern still lies in the low scanning rate on the receiver side.

Regarding the attenuation, you are definitely right! However, I am doing this on some preliminary requirement for some adaptive power adjustment depending on the RxPower of the received advertisement.

Would you know how I can scan at a faster rate or send multiple advertisements at once?

Comment: "Would you know how I can scan at a faster rate or send multiple advertisements at once?" - sorry, no, but if you add the TxPower field to your advertising peripheral, you can estimate the signal path loss (i.e. RxPower - TxPower), and use that to adjust the TX power of both devices.